# Custom confirm message with 'Yes' and No option not coming

Tags: javascript, jquery

On clicking done. i am not getting the custom confirmation box with yes no    option.

```
        <html>
        <head>
<style type="text/css">
            body { font-family: sans-serif; }
            #confirmBox
          {
        display: none;
        background-color: #eee;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        position: fixed;
        width: 300px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        padding: 6px 8px 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #confirmBox .button {
        background-color: #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        padding: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 80px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #confirmBox .button:hover
    {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    #confirmBox .message
    {
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    </style>
        <script language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
            alert("Inside");
            var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
            alert("confirmBox");
            confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
            confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
                confirmBox.hide();
            });
            confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
            confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
            confirmBox.show();
        }
        function isAnchorTagClicked(){
         alert("yes");
         doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes()
                    {
                        alert("Yes Clicked");
                    }, function no()
                    {
                        // do nothing
                    });
        }

        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="confirmBox">
            <div class="message"></div>
            <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
            <span class="button no">No</span>
        </div>
        <button onclick="isAnchorTagClicked()">Done</button>
        </body>
        <html>
```

Both the Alerts i am getting inside the function doConfirm(). But the confirmation window is not coming. Kindly help me out.

Comment: You missed the closing quote on the buttons onclick event

Comment: Added the missing quotes but still no luck.

Comment: Why do you have two copies of jQuery?

Comment: Script tags can not be self closing `<script />` is not valid...

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function{
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h6>Are you sure?</h6></div>')
    .dialog({
        title: 'Conform message',
        modal: true,
        zIndex: 99,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            Yes: function () {
                //some text    
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            No: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        close: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Onclick i need to show an alert message as shown above isAnchorTagClicked(). after that only confirm message should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code-

```js
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
        alert("Inside");
        var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
        alert("confirmBox");
        confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
        confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
            confirmBox.hide();
        });
        confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
        confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
        confirmBox.show();
    }
    function isAnchorTagClicked(){
     alert("yes");
     doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes()
                {
                    alert("Yes Clicked");
                }, function no()
                {
                    // do nothing
                });
    }
```

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
            #confirmBox
          {
        display: none;
        background-color: #eee;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        position: fixed;
        width: 300px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        padding: 6px 8px 8px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #confirmBox .button {
        background-color: #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        padding: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 80px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #confirmBox .button:hover
    {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    #confirmBox .message
    {
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="confirmBox">
        <div class="message"></div>
        <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="button no">No</span>
    </div>
    <button onclick="isAnchorTagClicked()">Done</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine for me when I fixed a self closing script tag and removed the duplicate reference to jQuery.

```
<script language="javascript" src="scripts/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
```

So those two lines just becomes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

And your code runs.

---

```js
function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
  var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
  confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
  confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function() {
    confirmBox.hide();
  });
  confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
  confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
  confirmBox.show();
}

function isAnchorTagClicked() {
  doConfirm("Are you sure?", function yes() {
    alert("Yes Clicked");
  }, function no() {
    // do nothing
  });
}
```

```css
#confirmBox { display : none; }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<div id="confirmBox">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <span class="button yes">Yes</span>
  <span class="button no">No</span>
</div>
<button onclick="isAnchorTagClicked()">Done</button>
```